# Send data from Laravel application using Sendinblue

Tags: laravel, api

Please I need to send daily a group of data from my LARAVEL application using Sendinblue API *[this how the external server API looks like **( api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts/identifier )** ]*, I've managed to used Sendinblue PHP code to send one contact on the time.

```
    <?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sendinblue.com/v3/contacts/identifier",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"attributes\":{\"newKey\":\"New Value\"}}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "api-key: My API"
  ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
?>
```

My question there is a way to send all data at once and daily in an automatic way?

Should I use a For each in the controller or there is another ways?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with Laravel scheduler.

[Read More about scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling)